# Can't send some cookie in jMeter request

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I try to conduct load tests of a web application. I am having problem with authorization when I hit api request i got 401 even though I am logged in/authorized.
I know that problem is that when I hit API in request headers there are being send some cookies. There is user.id and my HTTP cookie manager is not grabbing it. It grabs only one another cookie. The user.id is being generated by Warden manager.
[JMeter requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qxa9.png)
[Real request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKEqI.png)

I have been trying setting **CookieManager.save.cookies=true** and **CookieManager.check.cookies=false** in user.properties.
Script was generated by Blazemeter.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots don't tell the full story.

What HTTP Cookie Manager is doing is:

- Extracting cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header and stores them internally
- On subsequent request(s) if the domain and path match, the cookie is not expired, etc. the HTTP Cookie Manager adds the cookie(s) to [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) request header

If JMeter doesn't send the `Cookie` header you're expecting it to send - most probably there is a problem with the cookies, you [can enable debug logging for the HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

and then inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

It might be the case choosing less restrictive policy, i.e. `netscape` will help to work around the problem:

[image]